# Airport Extreme PPPoE auth and wireless

Tags: macbook-pro, airport

My provider asks for a PPPoE authentication for internet and I don't know how to do it with Airport Extreme in order to have the wireless working. I can connect to the internet via ethernet using the provided credentials, but the wi-fi has no internet connection, probably because there's no bridge between the wi-fi and the ethernet on Airport Extreme.

Any idea how I can make it work so I can have both ethernet and wi-fi working?

Comment: The PPPoE is for the Modem to the out of the wall cable. Connect your Mac with Ethernet cable to the modem to set it up. Disconnect the Mac and connect the Modem with the Airport Extreme using a Ethernet cable. Now you can set up the Airport Extreme to broadcast the WifI.

Comment: What they provide is a wireless modem which has no gigabit port and I really don't want to lose that one. I was hoping for a way to bypass it since the airport extreme can make pppoe authentication, tried and tested. It's just the wifi not using those pppoe credentials.

Comment: Who is they ? there is usually a cable connection to the modem.  How is the "Modem" connected to the provider ? If "they" provided you with a modem and a router in one then there should be the wifi info on the back of it so you can connect to it.

Comment: They (the provider) sent this modem which has only one LAN working and a wireless router which can't go further than 300mb/s. In order to use the gigabit port I must connect my airport directly to the modem and specify the PPPoE credentials in the Thunderbolt Ethernet connection that I create. That works allright and I have my gigabit but no wireless on the Airport. I could of course link that wireless router to my Airport Lan port and broadcast from it to Wi-fi my home but I was really hoping on bypassing the wireless router they provided and make it work with the modem <-> Airport alone.

Comment: sorry, this is to much guessing. Unless you are able to state the provider, and the model names for your hardware I can not help you further.

Answer (score 2):

From your description you have a modem provided by your ISP and a separate access point or wireless router given by them that at the moment gives you Wi-Fi access to the internet.

You have to replace this access point or router with your Airport Extreme.
Open (or download, if you're on a Windows box) the Airport Utility app that will allow you to configure the Airport Extreme. Then follow the instructions provided at the [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH5099?locale=en_US) page:

> ### AirPort Utility 6.x: Connect to the Internet using PPPoE
>
> Some DSL and cable modem Internet service providers require you to use
>   Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet (PPPoE) to connect to the
>   Internet.
>
> If you’re using a DSL or cable modem, make sure it’s connected to the
>   telephone or cable jack, and to your wireless device’s wide area
>   network (WAN) port before setting up your base station.
>
> 1. Open AirPort Utility, located in the Utilities folder in the Applications folder, select the device you want to set up, then click
>      Edit. Enter the password if necessary.
> 2. Click Internet, then choose PPPoE from the Connect Using pop-up menu.

[image: Airport Utility PPoE 6.3.5]

> 3. Enter the account name, password, and any other information your Internet service provider gave you. When you set up your base station
>      or your AirPort Time Capsule to connect using PPPoE, the device
>      receives an IP address from your ISP automatically, and uses DHCP and
>      NAT to share that IP connection with computers on your wireless
>      network.
> 4. Choose Always On, Automatic, or Manual from the Connection pop-up menu. If you choose Always On, your wireless device stays connected to
>      your modem and the Internet as long as the modem is turned on.
>
>    - If you choose Automatic or Manual from the Connection pop-up menu, you need to choose an increment, such as “10 minutes,” from the
>        “Disconnect if idle” pop-up menu. If you don’t use an Internet app
>        after the period of time has passed, you are disconnected from the
>        Internet.
>    - If you choose Automatic, your wireless device connects to the modem, which connects to the Internet when you use an app that
>        requires an Internet connection, such as an email, instant message, or
>        web app.
>    - If you choose Manual, you need to connect the modem to the Internet when you use an app that requires an Internet connection.
> 5. Choose an increment of time, such as 30 minutes, from the “Disconnect if idle” pop-up menu if you want to force the base station
>      to disconnect from the Internet when it isn’t used for the specified
>      amount of time.
> 6. Click Update to reset the wireless device with the new settings. If your web browser reports a connection error when you access the
>      Internet, wait until your computer is connected to the AirPort network
>      and make sure the network is connected to the Internet.
>
> To check the connection, use the wireless connection status icon in
>   the menu bar on a Mac, and the wireless network icon in the status
>   tray on a Windows computer.

On the Wireless tab you want to select "Create a wireless network" and specify the security, SSID and password. You can check additional options but let's keep it simple.

[image: Airport Utility Wireless]

On the Network tab you have to select "DHCP and NAT" on the Router Mode (it does not allow me to modify it, probably because I selected "Create a wireless network" on the Wireless tab).

[image: Airport Utility Network]

Please check your settings and comment if this does not solve your question.